# I have a javascript function, and I can't tell what I've done wrong

Tags: javascript

This is a program to ping several hosts and track their

Here is the offending function

```
function parseHistory(){
for(i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++){
    var countTotal = 0;
    var countSuccessful = 0;
    var timeTotal = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < history[hosts[i]].length; j++){
        if(history[hosts[i]][j].success){
            countTotal++;
            countSuccessful++;
            timeTotal += history[hosts[i]][j].time;
        } else {
            countTotal++;
        }
    }
    var uptimePercent = Math.round(countSuccessful / countTotal * 10000) / 100 + '%';
    var averageTime = Math.round(timeTotal / countSuccessful * 100) / 100;
    console.log('--- ' + hosts[i] + ' has ' + uptimePercent + ' uptime with an average round-trip time of ' + averageTime + 'ms');
}
console.log('---');
}
```

Where `hosts` is an array of strings, and `history` is an object that stores several arrays of result objects.

My main problem is with this `for` loop, it seems to be doing the math wrong but I can't tell where.

Here is the output my program produces after about 30 seconds

```
--- google.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 33ms
--- yahoo.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 112ms
--- <redacted> has 0% uptime with an average round-trip time of NaNms
--- 127.0.0.1 has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 2ms
---
--- google.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 11.67ms
--- yahoo.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 38ms
--- <redacted> has 66.67% uptime with an average round-trip time of 1ms
--- 127.0.0.1 has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 1.33ms
---
--- google.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 7.6ms
--- yahoo.com has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 23.4ms
--- <redacted> has 80% uptime with an average round-trip time of 0.75ms
--- 127.0.0.1 has 100% uptime with an average round-trip time of 1.2ms
```

The average times seem to be decreasing after every ping, but for no reason. It looks like a math error somewhere to me but I can't find it.

Can you tell me where my error is?

Full source: http://pastebin.com/G0mfBTPe

Comment: If it were a syntax error, the code wouldn't do anything at all and you'd see an error in the developer console.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't realize what I typed.

Comment: Is the `history` the same for all 3 "reports" in your example, e.g. should the # of ms be the same for all 3 lines of "google.com has ..." ?

Comment: No, it is not the same. The program outputs the statistics for all hosts every 10 seconds, based on the data in the history object, which is structured like this: `{'google.com':[<array of result objects>], 'yahoo.com': [etc...]}`

Comment: Can you post the history data (maybe in the pastebin or somewhere else), I'm trying to understand what that average ms _should be_ for each instance.

Comment: I calculate the average round-trip time based on the all the round-trip times for each result added up together, divided by the number of successful round-trips. The non-successful round-trips are not included in `timeTotal`

Comment: Have you looked at the the history data and totalled up the numbers by hand to check the answers?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m6DumxNc

Comment: My apologies, it appears that the function is working correctly, but the npm module I'm using (net-ping) is returning inaccurate `Date` objects that cause the round-trip time to be a 1 or 0 when it should be higher. I'll look into being able to calculate the time myself. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CodingGorilla Thanks for your help, after I started recording my own date objects, I'm not receiving those strange readings anymore. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

From your pastebin, I noticed that you continuously are lengthening the `history[host]` list:

```
setInterval(ping, pingIntervalMs, host, function(result){
    history[host].push(result);
    historyChanged = true;
});
```

What does the "result" structure look like?  Perhaps you are pushing objects that default to ".success" but have zero ".time".